# allow users to continue the survey (webform) if closed by accident

Tags: 7, users, webforms

I wonder if there is a way of let users continue with survey (webform) in case they close the browser or the tab. For example:

I have a very long webform survey, it has like 30 questions, if Users start answering the survey today I need to let them continue with it if they close it and reopen it tomorrow.

example the url ot my survey is "node/1"

so if user begins the survey and closes it, then tomorrow he must be able for login and go to "node/1" and continue with the survey, right now users have to start over if they close the tab.

any idea? suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. Go to your webform and add page break type wherever you want to split the form.

[image]

Then go to Form Settings and check Automatically save as draft between pages and when there are validation errors. or Show "Save draft" button.

[image]

If you want to go further, meaning if you want to save a draft when user closes the browser. check [Use AJAX to auto save a draft](https://www.drupal.org/node/1319926)